# SQL use of OVER and PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table;

```
ClientID    | Location  | Episode   | Date  
001         | Area1     | 4         | 01Dec16  
001         | Area2     | 3         | 01Nov16  
001         | Area2     | 2         | 01Oct16  
001         | Area1     | 1         | 01Sep16  
002         | Area2     | 3         | 21Dec16  
002         | Area1     | 2         | 21Nov16  
002         | Area1     | 1         | 21Oct16
```

And I'm looking to create 2 new columns based to the latest episode of the client

```
ClientID    | Location  | Episode   | Date  | LatestEpisode     | LatestLocation   
001         | Area1     | 4         | Dec   | 4                 | Area1  
001         | Area2     | 3         | Nov   | 4                 | Area1   
001         | Area2     | 2         | Oct   | 4                 | Area1  
001         | Area1     | 1         | Sep   | 4                 | Area1  
002         | Area2     | 3         | Dec   | 3                 | Area2  
002         | Area1     | 2         | Nov   | 3                 | Area2  
002         | Area1     | 1         | Oct   | 3                 | Area2
```

I have worked out I can use `OVER` to work out the LatestEspisode: 
`LatestEpisode = MAX(Episode) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID)`

But can't work out how to get the LatestLocation?

EDIT: Sorry if I haven't got the format right, this is my first post. I was trying to look at how to post correctly but I found it quite confusing

I have searched stackoverflow many times over the last 3 days and have found various ways using `OVER` and `ROW NUMBER()` but I don't have a lot of experience of them. Many of the examples I had found previously were fine for producing an aggregated table but I want to keep the full table, this is why I thought using `OVER` was the way to go.

Comment: add what you already tried as proof that you already tried something

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Please use both the product and the version tag.

Comment: Still missing the complete query you tried, please read why this is important [mcve]

Comment: Sorry davejal if I messed this up. I spent about an hour trying to put the post together. I found it a bit confusing. How did you input the tables like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql server 2012 version introduced the [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) function,
That enables you to write your select query like this:

```
SELECT  ClientID, 
        Location, 
        Episode, 
        [Date], 
        LatestEpisode = FIRST_VALUE(Episode) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY [Date] DESC), 
        LatestLocation = FIRST_VALUE(Location) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) 
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Genius that's it. Thanks very much Zohar.  This is a simple solution for it . Sorry to you all if I have messed up the requirements for posting. I have been using the website for learning how to code but it is my first post and I spent about an hour trying to work out how to put the actual post together. Thanks for all the answers and input

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I would do this with `cross apply`:

```
select e.*, e2.episode as LatestEpisode, e2.location as LatestLocation
from episodes e cross apply
     (select top 1 e2.*
      from episodes e2
      where e2.clientId = e.clientId
      order by e2.episode desc
     ) elast;
```

Although you can express this logic with window functions, the lateral join (implemented in SQL Server using the `apply` keyword) is more natural way of expressing the logic.

If you are not familiar with lateral joins, you can think of them as a correlated subqueries in the `from` clause . . . but queries that allow you to return multiple columns.  I should add, though, that one of the main use cases is for table-valued functions, so it is a very powerful construct.

Comment: Shouldn't the order by be on `e2.[Date]` desc? and why `select *` when you only need `episode` and `location` ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . `Date` appears to be a three character string with no natural ordering.  And, `select *` is fine.  The optimizer chooses the columns that are needed.

Comment: Didn't know about the select * in the cross apply, thanks. I was guessing that the Date is of an appropriate data type and just typed in the question with this format

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to select `LatestEpisode` per each client and then you can use this value to identify row, where you can get `LatestLocation` from

```
SELECT *
    ,(
        SELECT Location
        FROM Episodes
        WHERE ClientId = MyTable.ClientId
            AND Episode = MyTable.LatestEpisode
        ) AS LatestLocation
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,MAX(Episode) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId) AS LatestEpisode
    FROM Episodes
    ) AS MyTable
```

You can also use **common table expression (CTE):**

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,MAX(Episode) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId) AS LatestEpisode
    FROM Episodes
    )
SELECT cte.*
    ,(
        SELECT Location
        FROM Episodes
        WHERE ClientId = cte.ClientId
            AND Episode = cte.LatestEpisode
        ) AS LatestLocation
FROM cte
```

Comment: please read [answer] to write a better answer, code only answers don't help the OP understand why this answer helps

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on it and able to produce the required result 
Please try below

```
Declare @Table table ( ClientID varchar(max), Location varchar(500), Episode int, Dated varchar(30)) 

Insert Into @Table 
Values ('001', 'Area1', 4 ,'01Dec16' )
,('001', 'Area2', 3, '01Nov16')
, ('001', 'Area2', 2, '01Oct16')  
,('001' ,'Area1' ,1, '01Sep16')
,('002' ,'Area2' ,3, '21Dec16') 
,('002' ,'Area1' ,2, '21Nov16') 
,('002' ,'Area1' ,1, '21Oct16') 


; WITH LL AS 
(
SELECT CLientID ,MAX(CAST (Dated as Date)) as maxdate
FROM @table 
GROUP BY ClientID
) 
, Area AS 
(
SELECT Location, x.ClientID, x.Dated FROM @Table x INNER JOIN LL b ON x.ClientID = b.ClientID AND x.Dated = b.maxdate
) 
SELECT a.*
, LatestEpisode = MAX(Episode) OVER(PARTITION BY a.ClientID)
, LatestLocation =  b.Location
FROM @Table a 
INNER JOIN Area b ON a.ClientID = b.ClientID
```